# What is the distribution of wand lengths?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

Wands come in a multitude of lengths in the *Harry Potter* universe, but what is the most common length for a wand to be, based on the wands we've seen and heard of in universe (including wands that don't currently have an owner)?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202947/did-ollivander-actually-use-his-measurements/202968#202968

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Based on the [known wands in the Wizarding World](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Wand) we can come up with the following information:

- Max Length: 18"
- Min Length: 7"
- Average Length: 10.92" (not an actual wand length because wands lengths are in 1/4" increments)
- Median Length: 10.375" (not an actual wand length because wands lengths are in 1/4" increments)
- **Mode Length: 9"**

So with the mode length, which is most commonly occurring number, the answer to your question would be 9". However, when taking into account the distribution, you are probably going to get wand greater than 9".

A wizard is most likely to receive a wand between 9.00" and 11.50" which account for ~62% (26/42) of all wands. The most common range of wands is 10" or greater but less than 12" (10.00" to 11.75"), accounting for ~38% (16/42). This matches up nicely to Ollivanders own comments on the matter:

> Most wands will be in the range of between nine and fourteen inches. While I have sold extremely short wands (eight inches and under) and very long wands (over fifteen inches), these are exceptionally rare.
>
> <sup>[Wand Lengths & Flexibility by J.K. Rowling on Wizarding World](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-lengths-and-flexibility)</sup>

---

There are 42 wands for which the length is mentioned at some point in the series.

<sub>*Note on lengths: Some of the lengths are derived directly from text of the books or similar written canon (interviews, games, etc.) but others are taken from the measurement of the props in the films. The prime example being Lucius' 18" wand.</sub>

- 18.00" - 1 - [Lucius Malfoy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/236676/57310)
- 16.00" - 1 - Rubeus Hagrid
- 15.00" - 1 - Albus Dumbledore (The Elder Wand)
- 14.00" - 2 - Ron Weasley (2nd wand), Player Choice in *Hogwarts: Mystery*
- 13.50" - 1 - Tom Riddle
- 12.75" - 2 - Bellatrix Lestrange, Garrick Ollivander
- 12.25" - 1 - Cedric Diggory
- 12.00" - 3 - Charlie Weasley (passed down as Ron's 1st), 2 Player Choices in *Hogwarts: Mystery*
- 11.50" - 1 - Silvanus Kettleburn
- 11.25" - 2 - Player Choices in *Hogwarts: Mystery*
- 11.00" - 4 - Harry Potter, James Potter, 2 Player Choices in *Hogwarts: Mystery*
- 10.75" - 1 - Hermione Granger
- 10.50" - 1 - Celestina Warbeck
- 10.25" - 4 - Horace Slughorn, Lily Potter nee Evans, Remus Lupin, Viktor Krum
- 10.00" - 3 - Draco Malfoy, Snatcher's Wand (used by Harry), Jacob (character from *Hogwarts: Mystery*)
- 9.50" - 3 - Fleur Delacour, Minerva McGonagall, Sybill Trelawney
- 9.25" - 2 - Peter Pettigrew, Ron Weasley (after he took it from Peter; note: this is the same wand... may need to take it out and recalculate)
- 9.00" - 5 - Gilderoy Lockhart, Quirinus Quirrell, Sir Cadogan, 2 wands made by Ollivander but never given to a character
- 8.75" - 1 - Mary Cattermole
- 8.50" - 1 - Made by Ollivander but never given to a character
- 8.00" - 1 - Dolores Umbridge
- 7.00" - 1 - Made by Ollivander but never given to a character

[image: Fancier column graph of wand lengths]

Comment: This is a very average answer.

Comment: @Valorum It is just a mode of delivering information to the median user.

Comment: @Valorum There's no need to be mean.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Haha. I bet you and Skooba think you're co-medians.

Comment: This met my every expectation.

Comment: So what's the modal of this story?

Comment: Given Ollivander's quote about big, dramatic personalities getting bigger wands, I wonder what it says about Lucius Malfoy that he got the longest wand recorded by a considerable margin?

Comment: Looks like the good characters have the wands near the median and average, while the evil ones tend to stand out and be in extremes.

Comment: ... how can the median not be an actual wand length??

Comment: @kutschkem That works for odd-length lists. For even-length lists, the median is the mean of the two middle elements.

Comment: Is it really appropriate to count wands never given to a character?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, because while we do not see them given out, we can assume they will be at some point.

Comment: @Skooba But I don't think that represents a valid sample of wands used by wizards. If Ollivander had shown a box of 5-inch wands and said "these are the shortest I can make", that wouldn't make them the most popular wand size.

Comment: @user253751 but that isn't the question. The question is what is the most common sized wand, there is no _in use_ qualifier.  Almost all the wands we are in use because that is the easiest way to encounter them. For all we know there might be bias in the wands we do see because we only see people important to the story and therefore they have more unique wands. I can only present what the data set allows.

Comment: @Skooba - I was going to make that comment. We spend almost all of our time with the wizarding equivalent of the aristocracy and monarchy.

Comment: @Skooba Well then it still applies: If Ollivander had shown a box of 5-inch wands and said "these are the shortest I can make", that wouldn't make them the most common wand size.

Comment: @user253751 but it would, but not he most common length in use.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage No, we know that Ollivander is not stupid, and therefore although he may have one box of really short wands, he has many more boxes of normal-length wands.  The question was about which wands are most common in the wizarding world, not just the ones shown.

Comment: The point stands that they'd still be usable wands, as you said he's not an idiot

Comment: @user253751 The question was about the distribution and this answer answers that as best as is plausibly possible with the information we have. Unless someone has a quote somewhere saying that the average wizard uses smaller wands than what we've seen (or can otherwise proof it to be more than a valid assumption), this is it.