# Why is Lucius Malfoy's Wand so Long?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

It is stated in various places that [Lucius Malfoy's wand is 18" in length](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Wand).

This seems to exceedingly long as Ollivander states:

> In my experience, longer wands might suit taller wizards, but they tend to be drawn to bigger personalities, and those of a more spacious and dramatic style of magic.
>
> Most wands will be in the range of between nine and fourteen inches. While I have sold extremely short wands (eight inches and under) and very long wands (over fifteen inches), these are exceptionally rare.
>
> <sup>[Wand Lengths & Flexibility by J.K. Rowling on Wizarding World](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-lengths-and-flexibility)</sup>

The other longest wand we know of is Hagrid's at 16" and this is confirmed by the text in the book

> "Rubeus! Rubeus Hagrid! How nice to see you again.... Oak, sixteen inches, rather bendy, wasn't it?"
>
> "It was, sir, yes," said Hagrid.
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*</sup>

Now Lucius certainly has a "bigger personality" and probably has a "dramatic style of magic" so he probably would have a longer wand. However 18" still seems exaggerated.

I have heard that the 18" length comes from the prop wand used by Jason Isaacs while performing his role as Lucius. Now [that prop](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Lucius_Malfoy%27s_walking_stick) was concealed in a walking stick and also had a snake-head handle (which was later broken off by Voldemort). **So can we confirm the actual length of the prop and is the length factored with or without the snake-head handle?**

Comment: To add, are you looking for an out-of-universe answer? because your last sentence seems like you are. seems a bit confusing  to me

Comment: @Shreedhar Well it would be in-universe but it would be film only canon. The prop was used in the film so the length could be known. The books definitely do not state the length of Lucius' wand and I don't think JKR has commented on it.

Comment: The [Harry Potter: The Wand Collection](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Harry_Potter:_The_Wand_Collection) factbook lists his wand as 17 ¼''

Comment: Shrek: "Do you think he's maybe compensating for something?"

Comment: *Wands are only as powerful as the wizards who use them. Some wizards just like to boast that theirs are bigger and better than other people's.* - Hermione Granger

Comment: Seems like a topic for fan fiction ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to find a copy of *[Harry Potter: The Wand Collection](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Harry_Potter:_The_Wand_Collection)* as suggested by [@Valorum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/valorum) in the comments and I went down quite a rabbit hole...

**Indeed, the books lists the wand at 17.25 inches. So I am still at loss as to where the Wiki gets the 18" from...**

[image: Lucius Malfoy's wand with length measurement]

However, it does not give any detail if that is just the wooden part or inclusive of the silver handle. Although I do suspect it *does* include the handle as Narcissa Malfoy's wand was used as a blueprint example in the opening of the book on how the props were sent to production. This blueprint shows the measurement from tip to base including the handle, and Narcissa's wand has an ornate handle (although not quite as ornate as Lucius').

[image: wand blueprint]

What is really surprising is that there are a total of 60 wands listed in the book, with 59 measurements given (Hagrid's umbrella is the lone exception) and all the wands seems to be exceptionally long compared to what we know from book canon.

- Minimum: 10.50" (Prof. Umbridge)
- Maximum: 17.50" (Prof. Lockhart)
- Average: 14.35"
- Median: 14.25"
- Mode: 14.00"

14" is upper end of of normal wands in book canon and is the average length here! 42 of the 59 wands (71%) are 14" and greater.

Now my best guess as to why this is because of the medium. Film is visual and I assume the production team wanted wands to be highly visible which also explains their ornate nature. The Wand Collection also lets us know the actor portraying Lucius, Jason Isaacs, was responsible for most of his look in the film.

> It is actor Jason Isaacs who first asked director Chris Columbus if his character could have a cane. Columbus asked, "Why, is there something wrong with your leg?" Isaacs replied, "No, I just think it would be good for pointing and gesturing and I could pull a wand out of it." So it is that Lucius's walking stick with its concealed wand became incorporated into his costume for the Harry Potter films.
>
> Isaacs confesses he thinks his is the coolest wand in the wizarding world and that it makes his character, Lucius Malfoy, walk a bit taller.
>
> Lucius is a known practitioner of the Dark Arts with his wand, including Unforgivable Curses. He attempted to perform the Killing Curse on Harry in Har_ry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, but his once-enslaved house-elf Dobby interfered and repelled him.
>
> The handle of Lucius's wand, a fang-bearing snake head, gleams with emerald gems-the color of Slytherin-for its eyes.
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter: The Wand Collection - Lucius Malfoy*</sup>